# Convert String From RSS feed to DateTime for Datatbase

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

I have the value of `Thu, 06 Nov 2014 10:47:21 GMT` coming from RSS feed. I want to save this string to a DateTime field in MS SQL Database. But I get an error

> 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'

```
DateTime date  = Convert.ToDateTime(a.PubDate);
string dateString = a.PubDate;

DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddd dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ttt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

db.Entry(a).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forget to use `,`  wrongly used `ttt` format specifier *even if it exist*. There are only `t` and `tt` specifiers and they are for AM/PM designator.

```
string s = "Thu, 06 Nov 2014 10:47:21 GMT";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

You need to use `GMT` part as a literal string delimiter because time zone abbreviation names are not standardized. For example; `CST` can be Central Standard Time or China Standard Time or Cuba Standard Time.